# Convert INT to String when using STUFF Function in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert an `INT` but it is having an issue with the conversion.

> Conversion failed when converting the `nvarchar` value '245428,246425' to data type `int`.

The query I am using:

```sql
SELECT STUFF
       ( 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), NumField) 
            FROM Table A 
            WHERE ID = 218554 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) ,1,1,''
       )
```

I use this as a subquery in a larger table like so:

```
SELECT 
    Field1,
    Field2, 
    CASE WHEN criteria = '1'
         THEN     (SELECT STUFF( 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), NumField) 
                FROM Table A 
                WHERE ID = 218554 
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) ,1,1,''
           ))
    END 
FROM 
    Table B
```

The `STUFF` query runs fine when it's executed on it's own but when I run it in the full query it comes up with the conversion error.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that replicates the issue please? I can't see anything that would cause the problem; unless `A.ID` isn't a `int`.

Comment: I can't [replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=016b685cdb6d006e5b4450511d5d15c2) your problem.

Comment: You aren't using `STUFF`, you're using the XML string concatenation technique. STUFF just removes some characters. The error you posted can't be raised by *this* query. It looks like you're converting this into an INT, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: You'd get the same error in SQL Server 2017 using the `STRING_AGG` aggregate function. Whatever causes the conversion would still try to convert `'245428,246425'` to an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are not showing the full query -- or at least the full `case` expression.  A `case` expression returns a *single* value with a single type.

When there are type conflicts, then SQL Server has to determine the single overall type, according to its rules.  If one `then` returns an integer and another returns a string, then the `case` expression is an integer (**not** a string).  So, the string is converted to an integer.

You can see this problem with much simpler logic:

```
select (case when 1=1 then 'a' else 0 end)
```

Even though the `else` is never execution, the type of the expression is determined at compile time -- and `'a'` cannot be converted to an integer.